# How i can convert json into xml without the elements index numbers?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, browser, xml-parsing

I am trying to implement the following code that is allowing me to convert json to xml. But i don't want to get output in the form of element index such as starting from <0> and closing tag as  similary second node starting from <1> and ending as . I have big xml big json code that is why it is creating index tags such as <0>  and so on. I want to display my xml without these index tags. The code is as below:-

```
function convertJSon2XML() 
{
$("#xmlArea").val(x2js.json2xml_str($.parseJSON($("#jsonArea").val())));
}

$("#xmlArea").val("<root><child><textNode>First &amp; Child</textNode></child><child><textNode>Second 
Child</textNode></child><testAttrs attr1='attr1Value'/></root>");

convertJSon2XML();

$("#convertToXmlBtn").click(convertJSon2XML);
```

For reference i am also attaching output that what is meant by index tag. At the very start there is tag <0> and this is going so on. such as <1> then <2> and so on. So due to these index tags such as <0> , i am unable to read my xml in browser. I want to convert json to xml without these index tags such as <0> and so on. Please help.

Output:- [image: This is how the output is displaying. Starting from <0> tag.]

Answer (score -1):

It may be converted to this JSON.

```
{
  "root": {
    "child": [
      {
        "textNode": "First & Child"
      }, 
      {
       "textNode": "Second \nChild"
      }
    ], 
    "testAttrs": {
      "-attr1": "attr1Value", 
      "-self-closing": "true"
    }
  }, 
  "#omit-xml-declaration": "yes"
}
```